# Compare subsection of configparser file

Tags: python, dictionary, compare, configparser

I just started working with [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) and it looks interesting but I got stack with one idea that I have. I am trying to compare all sections in my configurationFile.ini with the first section.

Demonstration example of configurationFile.ini:

```
[DefaultSection]
key1    : value1
key2    : value2
key3    : value3
.
.
.
keyn    : valuen

[Section2]
key1    : value5
key2    : value6
key3    : value7
.
.
.
keyn    : valuen

[Section3]
key1    : value8
key2    : value9
key3    : value10
.
.
.
keyn    : valuen
```

What I am trying to do is to compare each section with the default section and see if there are any differences in the subsections. I want to see if the keys of all the rest of the sections match with the default keys, the values I do not care. In case that a key is not matching it should be printing the missing key:

For example: `section(n) is missing key(5)`

I am using double dictionaries which I think is the most suitable way of finding the difference but my skills are limited and I can not find the solution.

Sample of code loading and parsing the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pprint
import ConfigParser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    configObj = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    configObj.read('configurationFile.ini')
    listOfSections = configObj.sections()

    doubleDictionary = {}
    for section in listOfSections:
        doubleDictionary[section] = configObj.items(section)

    pprint.pprint(doubleDictionary)

    """{'dictionary_1': [('key_1', 'value_1'),
                         ('key_2', 'value_2'),
                         ('key_3', 'value_3')],
        'dictionary_2': [('key_1', 'value_4'),
                         ('key_2', 'value_5')],
        'dictionary_3': [('key_1', 'value_6'),
                         ('key_2', 'value_7')]}"""
```

I want to compare all the key(s) of dictionary_1 with all the dictionary(s) in the configurationFile.ini. The script should be generic of course, been able to handle n dictionaries and n keys.

Thank you all for your time and effort to assist me.

Answer (score 0):

I you use the special `DEFAULT` section then configparser will supply each missing key in a section with the one from the default when you read the file. This might not be what you want, but if you create your file like

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

config.set('DEFAULT', 'key1', "value1")
config.set('DEFAULT', 'key2', "value2")
config.set('DEFAULT', 'key3', "value3")

config.add_section('Section2')
config.set('Section2', 'key1', "value5")
config.set('Section2', 'key2', "value2")

with open("configurationFile.ini", 'w') as f:
    config.write(f)
```

then you can get the differing keys like this

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("configurationFile.ini")

for section in config.sections():
    for key in config.options(section):
        if config.get(section, key) != config.get('DEFAULT', key):
            print key + " of " + section + " differs from default"
```

Pay attention that the undefined `key3` of `Section2` takes the default value, so it will not be reported as differing. But `key2`, which was explicitly assigned a different value will.

`config.sections()` gives you every section *except* the default one, so no comparison of the default keys with themselves have to be carried out.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your time and effort reading and replying to my question. It has been some time that I had this problem and to be honest I did not spend time yet to solve it. I hope that during the weekend I might be able to spend some time and get back on you on this one. Again thank you for your time and effort.